# Interfacing a serial DAC

Tags: serial, dac, interface

I am trying to make a use of [AD5612](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/AD5602_5612_5622-278550.pdf) DAC. It has a serial interface and I can not fully understand how to properly drive it. Given that I will be using only one DAC in **normal operating mode** with **ADDR pin** set to ground, my first 8 bit frame should be 00011 **110**, following by the second frame with 00 **00** [D9:D6], and the third frame with [D5:D0]XX.

In particular, there are several questions:

1. Do I have to provide SERIAL BUS ADDRESS BYTE (frame 1) every time I want a new sample to be converted, or the frame 1 is only written on the power up?
2. Given the 10bit DAC, what should be the 2 LSB bits of frame 3?
3. When is the new sample available on the DAC ouput?
4. What's the purpose of the read mode, since I know the content of the register any way?

Here's the clock sequence for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That DAC uses I2C bus.

1. After every start condition you have to send device address.
2. The I2C protocol transmits/receives a total of 8 bits (without ACK) thus a byte is transmitted/received. If it has 10 data bits and 4 control bits, then it must use 2 bytes data (16 bits) thus some bits (2) remain unused. They should be set to 0 according to datasheet.
3. After sending all data bits to the device (register), maximum time required for producing stable output is \$10\mu \$seconds.
4. You can use the read function to make a simple error check. Write something to the DAC, then read it back and see if it is the same.

Comment: Do I have a control over the 10us period mentioned in 3? How do I make sure that the output signal is produced 10us after sending the last bit?

Comment: @Naz As long as the data bits are in the register the signal will be produced in maximum 10 us (datasheet page 3, output characteristics, Output Voltage Settling Time).

Comment: I see, but let's say that _t0_ =time after the last bit was written and _t1_ is 10us after _t0_. What is Vout within _t0_ : _t1_ frame? Is it the old value, or some intermediate unknown value?

Comment: @Naz "The voltage is tapped off by closing one of the switches connecting the string to the amplifier." (page 15). I guess this means that intermediate voltages are outputted.